# Use eBPF to change process's CPU affinity

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

Is it possible to change a process's CPU affinity with eBPF?
I checked all bpf helper functions, no directly related functions. But can use `bpf_get_current_task` to retrieve the task_struct. Is it possible to change a process's CPU affinity via modifying its task_struct in eBPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The object you get as a pointer from `bpf_get_current_task` is ready-only. And I don't know of any other way to change the CPU affinity with BPF today.